# how can i use adonis js and nuxt and electron and local database like mongoDB or Sqlite?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron, nuxt.js, adonis.js

I want to create an app, that can run for desktop 
and I will use nuxtjs and adonis.

My issue is how can I add electron js to it and use local Database like sqlite in it 
because when I create nuxt adonis app I cannot how can I add electron
to it and actually how can I handle my database in this desktop app

Comment: You may take a look at https://github.com/kisese/adonisjs-electron 
But i don't know why you should use Nuxt.js with Electron?

Comment: @ChristopherDosin, turns out there's a template for [that](https://github.com/nuxt-community/electron-template).

Answer (score 2):

> assuming that your other queries are solved after reading comments.. so explaining only mongodb part...

using some common variable & function names used widely in community to illustrate example...

like `mainWindow` or `cerateWindow`...

if you want to run `mongodb` from electron you can use `child_process.execFile` to spawn non-blocking process from electron..

you can run before or after of `createWindow`..

for before run it directly from main process and use `stdout` and `stderr` of `child_process` for possible outcomes...

and if you wants to run it after `createWindow` the send signal to run it from `mainWindow` through `ipcRenderer` or whatever you are comfortable with...

code example -

```
const { execFile } = require('child_process')

let mongoDbCP = execFile('path_to_mongod_file, ['--dabpath=path_to_db', 'any_other_args], { 'any_options': 'if_you_want_to_pass_for_child_process' }, (error) => { \* handle error *\ })

mongoDbCP.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});
```

if you are on `windows` then whenever you quit your app `mongod` will exit too...
but on `macos` you need to terminate manually before quitting with `killall [process_name]` or `kill -9 [process_pid]` explicitly ..